# Single FakeApp for all test in Play Framework

Tags: testing, playframework

I want to have single FakeApplication for all my test. 
My final goal is to set up database and use it in all test. They should access single database and share data in it. I can not use H2, because I use some MySQL features(fulltest search, for example). But if there is no started application, I can't call "DB.withTransaction" because there is started application yet. But it should start once, because it drops all tables and create new ones.
How can I do it?

Comment: Are you using Scala or Java? Which testing framework?

Comment: I am using scala and JUnit. I solved my problem next way: I just created singleton for my fake application, which is retrieved as a implicit val. So, all work about creating and cleaning database is done on first fetch.

Comment: Then consider posting your solution as an answer. That information can help somebody with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am using scala and JUnit. I solved my problem next way: I just created singleton for my fake application, which is retrieved as an implicit val. So, all work about creating and cleaning database is done on first fetch.